# Can rear shocks affect comfort at the front?

Tags: suspension, safety, shock-absorber

Can bad rear shocks affect the ride quality at the front of the car? Or are they only noticeable for back passengers?

My car was really "bouncy", so I replaced the front shocks. Even though the ride has become more comfortable, it is still far from ideal as I can feel every groove on the road. Should I also replace the rear shocks or do they have no impact on front comfort? Are there any other parts that I should consider changing/replacing?

There was a similar question, but the answers didn't really talk about comfort:
[How Important Are the Rear Shocks / Struts](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25573/how-important-are-the-rear-shocks-struts)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Isn't "comfort" a relative thing? It is very subjective. What does "ride comfort" mean to you? What is it doing it shouldn't be doing? What is it not doing it should be? There are ways to see if the shocks are bad which really has nothing to do with ride comfort.

Comment: A comfortable ride for me means that I don't notice the road. There is no bounce and no vibration. Currently my car bounces on even smooth roads (no potholes or bumps). The effect makes me sea-sick sometimes and it is not very pleasant. I don't feel like this when riding in other cars.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is yes - rear shocks can affect the comfort at the front.

According to the accepted answer below, replacing just the front shocks is not sufficient. It seems to be best to replace both the front and the rear shocks.
[My Ride is Still Very Bouncy after Changing the Struts and Strut Mounts](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26858/my-ride-is-still-very-bouncy-after-changing-the-struts-and-strut-mounts)

Comment: Bad rear shocks can also have you doing an unexpected 180 in a corner. It can seriously compromise the stability in cornering.