# How to make a car less bouncy?

Tags: suspension, safety

My 2016 Camry feels very "bouncy" even on seemingly smooth roads. It is bouncy at every speed, from 30km/h to 110km/h. I can feel every groove on the road. Which components should I modify/replace to achieve a more comfortable ride? I know that shock absorbers prevent the car from bouncing. So I have replaced the front shocks, but most of the bounce is still there. I am now considering my options:

- Replace rear shocks
- Replace springs
- Perform wheel balancing. I've already done wheel alignment and rotation.
- Get better tyres

What is the best option for me and is there anything else I should be thinking about? Is my car just "bouncy" by design and there is nothing I can do about it, other than getting a new car?

Comment: Bouncy could mean that your shock absorbers were too soft.  Feeling every groove in the road could mean your shock absorbers were too hard.  What is it you are feeling, a too soft or too hard ride?

Comment: It's a little hard to explain. I can feel when I am passing over a groove. As I pass over a groove the car bounces. Also when there are no grooves (smooth road) the car bounces at random intervals. In contrast when I drive in a "good" car over the same road I don't even feel the grooves. If the "good" car bounces then it is less frequent and the amplitude of each bounce is smaller (more dampening).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can rear shocks affect comfort at the front?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/82975/can-rear-shocks-affect-comfort-at-the-front)

Comment: Also as you said in your other answer whilecreplacing the rear shocks the front and also choice of tires makes a difference. One tire can work well or not on any car...

Comment: The other question is one I made about the same issue and I answered it partially myself. It is related, but not a duplicate. This question is asking for advice on which option I should choose. Please do not close it.

Comment: This will probably get closed for one of two reasons: the other question covers the topic and you are asking which of the choices is "best" - well the correct choice depends on what works in **your** situation. We can say shocks or tires but you have to find what works for you.

Comment: Ok so the problem can be either shocks or tires and there is no way to tell? Can we at least discard springs, given that this is a relatively new car? I am really desperate as no local mechanic can tell me what the issue is. So I am relying on you good people to help me out. I was hoping that changing the front shocks would solve it, but it hasn't. I feel devastated that I wasted $1200 for nothing.

Comment: Personally, I would have borrowed a set of wheels/tires to do a quick test and work from there... not spend $$$ on a guess.